# My SSIS package using ole db command to update oracle, the update commands won't work

Tags: oracle, ssis, oledbcommand

BIDS 8.0
oracle 11.g client is installed. the original server was 11g and it worked. we upgraded the server to oracle 12c. all ole db update commands will not work. There is no error from the output, just the table data not updated. any ideas?

Comment: Connection is auto commit?

Comment: So you see the task turn green?

Comment: @Ersin Gülbahar I assume the ole sql command will commit by default. but I did try to add begin ... commit; end; but no difference.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I ran the package by using DTEXec. when I open my package, the bids run button is grey out.

Comment: The problem is only on Update commands,  iş there any Insert

Comment: The package use a different connection type to handle insert. it's ok. it's ms oracle connector (attunity)

Comment: To get the run button to appear, you need to create a new (temporary) project and add your package to the project. You can only run when inside a project. What version of SSIS? Also do you know if you're running it in 32 or 64 bit mode? (what's the path to DTExec?) @ErsinGülbahar has a good point - I wonder if it just wasn't committed

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, thank you. I got it running and the box with update/delete operation is green, but the result is not commit. wondering is there a setting to force commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this

CREATE Procedure and sen parameters to it,  and handle the Update operation in Procedure

Do not forget use `commit` end of the dml statament

Comment: by creating the procedure you suggested, I figured out one of mine connection string is pointing to a wrong server. I really appreciate you take time helping me on this.